# traversing ListView using another CustomView i.e through up and down button in android

Tags: android, listview

I  am using a lisview then there is a requirment to traverse listview using up button and down button.

i have set

```
listview.setSelection(newPosition);
listview.requestFocus();
```

but it not traversing List.

Please suggest me with answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below :

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(newPosition);
```

**EDIT:**

And to set focus to the item use `setSelection` below given line:

```
listview.setSelection()
listview.requestFocus();
```

Comment: when i pressed android keyboard up and down button listview got focus but when we press custom up and down button then listview loose focus.

Comment: what did you mean by `android keyboard up and down button` ?

Comment: android keyboard up and down means D-Pad button

Comment: are you running in simulator ? try running your app on actual device, it will work. And make sure to put above statement on your click event of buttons.

Comment: i had tried on device but on setting smoothScrollToPosition(newPos) only scroll the list upto new position but there is no focus on new position. i need focus on new position.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but this not work in my case.  think the problem is that when i click on up button or down button the focus goes on these button and listview loose focus. can you help me in this case.